# Removing redundant semicolons in code with SyntaxRewriter

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to remove redundant semicolons in the code using a custom syntax rewriter.

```
public class Sample
{
   public void Foo()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Foo");
      ;
   }
}
```

The following syntax rewriter covers most scenarios as in the Sample class.

```
public class EmptyStatementRemoval : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
  public override SyntaxNode VisitEmptyStatement(EmptyStatementSyntax node)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

However when the semicolon has a leading or trailing trivia, returning null from the VisitEmptyStatement method removes the trivia, which is unintended.

```
public class Sample
{
   public void Foo()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Foo");
      #region SomeRegion
      //Some other code
      #endregion
      ;
   }
}
```

I couldn't determine how to return a node with only the leading and trailing trivia removing the semicolon. I tried to replace the semicolon token with another token using node.WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxToken) method, which turns out to be accepting only tokens of type SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken or throws an ArgumentException.

Comment: Is the semicolon considered part of `node.GetLeadingTrivia()`?

Comment: No, semicolons aren't trivia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach that could work is to replace the semicolon token with a *missing* semicolon token:

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitEmptyStatement(EmptyStatementSyntax node)
{
    return node.WithSemicolonToken(
        SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)
            .WithLeadingTrivia(node.SemicolonToken.LeadingTrivia)
            .WithTrailingTrivia(node.SemicolonToken.TrailingTrivia));
}
```

For your `#region` example, the result looks like this (notice the line containing only whitespace where the semicolon was):

```
public class Sample
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        #region SomeRegion
        //Some other code
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still wondering if this scenario is impossible without leaving a redundant whitespace.

Comment: @odulkanberoglu I think it is, but it would require more complicated code to detect what whitespace is "redundant".